# Integrating Spring cloud sleuth with Spring project

Tags: java, spring, slf4j, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am trying to integrate spring cloud sleuth with an existing spring application which uses jetty server.

I have added

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
</dependencies>
```

How should I pass the logger properties, logging pattern while starting the app? Right now, it does not read the properties file under /resources folder and no traceId or spanId is generated.

Most of the examples have used Spring Boot. Need help to figure out how to integrate this with a Spring application with jetty server.

Comment: _"Can someone share the steps"_ -- Sorry, that's not how this site works. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for details.  You try to do it, then ask a specific detailed question when you run into problems. Please also read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: Hi Jim, I have edited the question. Let me know your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Cloud Sleuth is Spring Boot based. Please use https://github.com/openzipkin/brave for non Spring Boot based applications.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin Grzejszczak